# How to get shop_url who install my shopify app first time

Tags: node.js, express, shopify, shopify-app

i am developing shopify app and it successfully work in my development store. but i have doubt that how i can get the shop url who will install my app from shopify app
following is url for install my app in particular shopify store
and this url call my callback url which generate permanent access_token

```
https://example.com/shopify?shop=shopname.myshopify.com

shop_url=shopname.myshopify.com
```

How to get this shop_url of shopify store who install my app very first time. can any one help me out with this

problem is how to set and where to get shop_url when my install app route call

```
https://example.com/shopify?shop=?
```

? where to get this. Can any one please help. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever Shopify sends your App a shop, the shop parameter is filled in. So you never have to wonder who is knocking at your door. You always know, with the exception perhaps of when you offer clickable service inside your own App. At that point, you might want to include the shop as a parameter too, for cases when your session times out. You can re-auth that way.